# Google Cloud load balancer POST data

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-stackdriver

We are using Google Cloud Stackdriver Logs for Load Balancer requests. As far as I see, we can get both GET and POST requests but we cannot reach POST payload. Is it possible to add POST payload to load balancer logs on Stackdriver?

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean the payload for all POST requests targeting the load balancer? To add, it is possible to add your own [Fluentd configuration files to the Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/agent-logs) to receive logs from the instance. Here is another [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs) on writing custom logs.

Comment: Logging POSTs is a great way to accidentally violate all sorts of security/privacy policies by putting passwords and other sensitive data in plain-text somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The data in all responses and the data in POST requests are not logged. This is the default for most web server/proxy software.

To inspect the data in the POST requests you'll need to look from the backend server or the client.